# How to install a Lb wireless network adapter on 12.04

Tags: wireless, usb

I purchased a BL-LW05-5R which is a wireless usb adapter how do I get the correct drivers for it to function?

Comment: I got a file that has a Linux folder. There is an install.sh but I have not a clue what to do with any of this. Here is the link to the download http://www.b-link.net.cn/down/BL-LW05-5R-linux-mac.rar

Comment: Have you tried plugging it in and trying it without drivers?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the description of your device from the terminal command: lsusb